# redirect page upon form submit after AJAX request that calls PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have an HTML page (`index.html`) that collects an email address and submits it to a server via an AJAX POST request. When the submit button is clicked, a javascript function executes the post request via AJAX and then the page submits to itself. I need to modify this so that the page submits to another page (`thankyou.html`) instead of to itself. I'm not sure how to do this in PHP. Is there a way to redirect a PHP page once a form is submitted and the AJAX query is executed?

I'm not sure if I should redirect the page in Javascript or in HTML or in PHP.

This is the form in `index.html`:

```
       <form class="email-form" method="POST" validate>
            <div class="email-input-container register-info-email">
                <input class="email-input" type="email" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" required name="MERGE0" id="MERGE0" placeholder="Email Address" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}$" aria-label="Email Address">
                <input id="sub-button" type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit" >
                <span class="success-message"><span class="sr-only">We got you</span></span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the post request in PHP (`post.php`)

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) ) :

    $data = [
            'email' => $_POST['email']
    ];

    if ( isset($_POST['platform']) ) :

            $data["device"] = $_POST['platform'];

    endif;

    syncMailchimp($data);

endif;
```

This is the AJAX request:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'post.php',
            data: data,
            success: function(data, status) {

                var message = JSON.parse(data).message;

                if (message == "error") {

                    $('.email-form small').html('An error has occurred. Please try submitting again.');
                    smallHighlight();

                } else if (message == "subscribed") {

                    $('.email-form small').html('You are already subscribed');
                    smallHighlight();

                } else {

                    $('.email-form').addClass('form-success');
                    $('.email-form small').attr('style', '');

                }

            },
```

Comment: If you need to redirect after calling PHP, redirect FROM the php with a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect to another page, put this after form is successfully submited

```
window.location = "http://www.example.com/thankyou.html";
```

EDIT: You shouldn't handle this redirect in PHP, because this is asynchronous call. You need to reference this somehow in you submit script

Hope it helps

Comment: Would it go in the success function of the AJAX call?

Comment: Yes, it should look more or less like this: `rest of the code …else {
            window.location = "http://www.example.com/thankyou.html";
        }`

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use this.

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/thankyou.html');
```

and In Javascript

```
window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/thankyou.html");
```

or

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/thankyou.html";
```